# How can I implement this type of week interval in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

[image]

I want to implement week interval feature where I can go on next by clicking on forward button.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can calculate the first and last day of the week by using this functions:

````
/// Find the first date of the week given a date.
/// ```
/// findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime.now());
///```
DateTime findFirstDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
  return dateTime.subtract(Duration(days: dateTime.weekday - 1));
}

/// Find last date of the week given a date.
///```
/// findLastDateOfTheWeek(DateTime.now());
///```
DateTime findLastDateOfTheWeek(DateTime dateTime) {
  return dateTime.add(Duration(days: DateTime.daysPerWeek - dateTime.weekday));
}
````

Example:

```
DateTime now = DateTime.now();
DateTime fday = findFirstDateOfTheWeek(now );
DateTime lday = findLastDateOfTheWeek(now);
```

Once you got the first two values you can add 7 days to the date time passed to get the following week and so on:

```
DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 7));
```

Hope it helps at least to get you started.